# Encapsulation for Rx Variables

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am building a project from Scratch using MVVM & RxSwift. While building the App I came into a point where I am building a ViewModel properties for login screen where it was built like this:

```
struct LoginViewModel {

let username = Variable<String>("")

init(username: String) {
    self.username.value = username
} }
```

In code reviewing another developer suggested that it would be written like this:

```
private let username = Variable("")
lazy var usernameObservable: Observable = self.username.asObservable()
```

As you can see, He created a private property which stores the data and public observable for omitting events. I have a concern in this approach which is that in that case we will duplicate all the properties in the ViewModel to achieve that. Which means that If I have 3 properties then Ill create another 3 corresponding properties. There should be a cleaner way to achieve this. Your recommendations would be very appreciated

Comment: A propos, RxSwift 4.0.0 "Deprecates Variable in favor of BehaviorRelay."

Comment: Your colleague prefers to encapsulate, and you prefer to keep it simple. Basically, what you want is to ensure unidirectional data flow. I personally find the MVVM approach way too verbose, and use Redux-like solution (https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift) instead. Not really an answer, rather an opinion.

Comment: @MaximVolgin Thank you Maxim :) The thing is that I dont want to store properties in ViewModel. I want it to be totally functional without any side effects. I used ReSwift for Unidirectional data flow once and It was great